# How to rotate image and arrow line from a fixed center point

Tags: iphone, xcode, image-rotation, icarousel

In my app i have a fix size of button/center points, and i wants to rotate arrow line and this attached image also rotate when i touch/scroll up/down.
  And i have made a demo in this i scroll only images using icarousel classes.
but i can't scroll both arrow and image scroll both at a time.
Please help me how to implement this.
[image]

and my code for only image scroll using icarousel is here..

```
  - (UIView *)carousel:(__unused iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex: (NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UIView *viewFor;
UIImageView *itemView;
if (view==nil) {

    viewFor=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    itemView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 120, 120)];
    [itemView.layer setCornerRadius:itemView.frame.size.width/2];
    [itemView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [viewFor addSubview:itemView];

        StikImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-140, 95, 140, 20)];
   StikImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
   [viewFor addSubview:StikImage];

  }
  else
  {
    viewFor=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    itemView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 120, 120)];
    [itemView.layer setCornerRadius:itemView.frame.size.width/2];
    [itemView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [viewFor addSubview:itemView];

        StikImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-140, 95, 140, 20)];
         StikImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [viewFor addSubview:StikImage];

  }
   itemView.image=[images objectAtIndex:index];
return viewFor;
 }
```

And here is my Custom type icrousel method for transform images

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform {

const CGFloat centerItemZoom = 1.6;
const CGFloat centerItemSpacing = 1.2;
const CGFloat centerItemYOffset = 100;
CGFloat spacing = [self carousel:carousel valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:1.3f];
CGFloat absClampedOffset = MIN(2.5, fabs(offset));
CGFloat clampedOffset = MIN(1.0, MAX(-1.0, offset));
CGFloat scaleFactor = 1.0 + absClampedOffset * (1.2/centerItemZoom - 1.0);
CGFloat yoffset = (1.0f - absClampedOffset) * centerItemYOffset;
offset = (scaleFactor * offset + scaleFactor * (centerItemSpacing - 1.0) * clampedOffset) * carousel.itemWidth * spacing;



if (carousel.vertical)
{
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, yoffset, offset, -absClampedOffset);

}
else
{
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offset, yoffset, -absClampedOffset);
}

transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 5.0f);
  return transform;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for rotate the image view

```
imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI/180);
```

*you can use what you want degree sizes are like 180, 90, 240, 270..., depends on your requirements "touch/scroll up/down"*

Comment: Firstly Thanks for answer @iSara but how i can set y offset and degrees   to scroll up/down arrow/line with respect of images.

Comment: @RAMA: Can you use above code with in scrollview delegate methods.

Comment: ..i can't...i m used iCarousel view for achieved this type in my code perfect for only images but now i want to add these arrows/lines attached with images ..these arrows also rotate at time with images at same angle how can i achieved this ..please help me..